# How to install toolbox for MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am just wondering, if I need a toolbox which not available in my MATLAB, how do I do that? For example: if I need image processing toolbox, how do I get it?

Answer (score 30):

first, you need to find the toolbox that you need. There are many people developing 3rd party toolboxes for Matlab, so there isn't just one single place where you can find "the image processing toolbox". That said, a good place to start looking is the [Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/) which is a Mathworks-run site for exchanging all kinds of Matlab-related material.

Once you find a toolbox you want, it will be in some compressed format, and its developers might have a "readme" file that details on how to install it. If it isn't the case, a generic way to attempt installation is to place the toolbox in any directory on your drive, and then add it to Matlab path, e.g., going to File -> Set Path... -> Add Folder   or Add with Subfolders (I'm writing for memory but this is definitely close).

Otherwise, you can extract all .m files in your working directory, if you don't want to use downloaded toolbox in more than one project.

Answer (score 6):

There are many toolboxes.  Since you mentioned one that is commercially available from MathWorks, I assume you mean how do you get a trial/license

http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/

There is a link for trials, purchase, demos.  This will get you in touch with your sales representative.  If you know your sales representative, you could just call to get attention faster.

---

If you mean just a general toolbox that is from a source other than MathWorks, I would check with the producer, as it will vary widely from "Put it on your path." to whatever their purchase and licensing procedure is.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ver`  it will list all the installed toolboxes and versions of the toolbox.

Answer (score -1):

For installing standard toolboxes:
Just insert your CD/DVD of MATLAB and start installing, when you see typical/Custom, choose custom and check the toolboxes you want to install and uncheck the others which are installed already.