# How do I add a new toolbox to my already installed Matlab version?

Tags: path, matlab

I need to add a toolbox to my Matlab Student version. I know that I have to download the toolbox files, place them in some directory and then specify a path.
However, I am not quite sure about where I have to place my files.

I downloaded two zip archives: 'Symbolic Math Toolbox (Common) 5.10' and 'Symbolic Math Toolbox 5.10'.

1. Where do I have to place them on Mac OSX Mountain Lion?
2. How and where do I specifiy the path?

Thank you all, this will help me a lot with my project!

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/install.html?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3389797/2180721 and it even appears as related.

Comment: @Oleg Komarov thanks, I see that you can place the toolbox files in any directory. However, do you happen to know the default directory that Matlab uses? Where does Matlab put the toolboxes when you chose to install them together with the main matlab installation?

Answer (score 8):

Ok, I figured it out: Here what you do on Mac OS X Mountain Lion:

Downloading the files/ toolbox:

1. Login to your MatWorks account.
2. Click on your name in the upper right corner.
3. Go to 'Manage Licenses' in the 'My Licenses' section on the left.
4. Click on 'Download products'
5. Select your Operating System (in this case Mac OS X)
6. Choose the option 'Choose products and versions to download for the platform(s) selected.' and click continue.
7. Select the toolboxes that you want and click continue.
8. A small window will pop up. Since you already have Matlab installed you don't want to tick Matlab. Just click continue.
9. Since I didn't get the automatic installer working I used the manual download. Click on 'try manual download.'
10. Download the installer, and the remaining files (2 per toolbox)

Now that you have downloaded everything we can continue with the installation.

Installing the toolbox:

1. Unzip the installer file (if it did not unzip automatically).
2. Place the ZIP FILES (IMPORTANT) of your toolbox inside the installer directory.
3. Double click the installer and follow the the instructions.

NOTE:

You might have to enter a file activation key. You can redownload it from the 'Manage License' page (the one we visited at the beginning) under the 'Activation and Installation' tab. There just click on 'Get license file' and you can download the license file and copy the file activation key.

Hope this is helpful to anyone! If so, give it a vote!
cheers!