# how to install a toolbox to matlab if I do not have administrative authorization

Tags: matlab

I plan to install SBEToolbox to the matlab in the pc where I do not have administrative access. I found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6PZoA55Q68
and other related links. But since I do not have administrative access, I really do not know where to get started. Can anyone help me please? Many thanks.

Comment: Well i guess this is not the place for asking this kind of hacking queries :)...  The simple guess will be to reference everything in your local folder, and add that folder onto the Matlab Path.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this particular toolbox. But in general: unpack the toolbox into a folder (preserving paths!) of your choosing, and then add that folder to your Matlab path.