# Undefined function or variable 'vl_nnconv'

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, conv-neural-network

I install MATLABRB2015 MATLAB  follwing tool BOX

- Version 8.6         (R2015b) Computer Vision System Toolbox
- Version 7.0         (R2015b) Image Acquisition Toolbox
- Version 4.10        (R2015b) Image Processing Toolbox
- Version 9.3         (R2015b) Parallel Computing Toolbox
- Version 6.7         (R2015b) Signal Processing Toolbox
- Version 7.1         (R2015b) Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox
- Version 10.1        (R2015b)

..
When I use `y = vl_nnconv(x, w, []) ;`
MATLAB give this error **Undefined function or variable 'vl_nnconv'.**
HOW this will solve?

Answer (score 1):

`vl_nnconv` appears to be a function from the 3rd party [MatConvNet](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/).  You'll need to download and install that toolbox.

Comment: Sir I download the version 1.0-beta17 #MATConvNet ...But how install it in MATLAB ....Kindly tell me step by step or screen shots.I will be very thhankfull..@Phil Goddard

Comment: See, for instance, [How to install toolbox for MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389545/how-to-install-toolbox-for-matlab).

Answer (score 0):

Installing matconvnet depends on whether you wanna use GPU or no.
if you do not have gpu the steps are very easy.
Step 1: download the package from their website 
http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/download/matconvnet-1.0-beta18.tar.gz

Step 2: uncompress the file at your local disk.

Step 3: if you want you can compile the package.
- cd MatConvNet
- addpath matlab
- vl_compilenn

Step 4: is the setup:
- run MatConvNet/matlab/vl_setupnn

that set. see this link:
http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/install/